# Can't view index.php of Zend Framework 1.0 after setting up Apache/Host requirements?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

**UPDATE**: the following error is coming up in the Apache error logs...

```
[Sat Dec 08 16:41:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' 
(include_path='/Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart/library:.:/php/includes:/Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox/Library/PHP/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library') 
in /Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart/public/index.php on line 18
```

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion) and I'm having problems getting the Zend framework set-up and running (just the basic QuickStart).

I'm using Apache 2.2.22

My localhost files are accessible from /Library/WebServer/Documents

I have PHP 5.3.15 running as well.

I've created a new project via the command line (using the zf.sh file) called 'quickstart' (as per the section on the Zend website recommends) and that is stored here: /Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart

I've followed both the official Zend website instructions and also an online book about installing Zend: http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts

My php.ini (`/private/etc/php.ini`) file has been updated to include the path to the `library` folder inside the ZendFramework directory...

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/<home>/Dropbox/Library/PHP/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library"
```

I've updated `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` so it includes...

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Ensure "localhost" is preserved unchanged pointed
# to the default document root for our system.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
</VirtualHost>

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickstart.local
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

...I've also updated `/etc/hosts` so it includes...

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   quickstart.local
```

I'm restarting Apache using `sudo apachectl graceful` (I've also used `sudo apachectl restart`)

So if I try and now access `http://localhost/` I see my `/Library/WebServer/Documents` directory and I can see PHP is running still with no problems. But if I try and access `http://quickstart.local/` I just get an empty page?

Can any one advise as to what the problem might be, what I'm missing and what I can do to get the initial 'welcome' page to display.

I'm sure I'm just missing someone small, but it's obviously causing problem enough for the basic page not to show.

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: You need to update the `include_path` in your `php.ini` to point to the folder where `ZendFramework` is located

Comment: I had already done that. Seems the solution is to have the ZendFramework folder inside the localhost root directory! Not sure why but the ini file couldn't follow the path to the Dropbox folder?

Comment: It'll work but is not best practice. Libraries are usually kept outside the document root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for others who may have followed this. The answer by Kamil, above, will work, but opens a security hole outside Apache's security configuration. That's fine as long as you know it and have another layer of security above Apache.

Another way to resolve the problem is to put the ZendFramework somewhere inside the root directory's hierarchy. Like: 
    DocumentRoot/Library/WebServer/Documents/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library 
or
    DocumentRoot/Library/WebServer/Documents/quickstart/public/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library 
Any path that's inside the root directory of your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a user permissions issue between the Zend files and the Apache process.

Since you can create the project using `zf.sh`, the Zend files are obviously there. But the fail you get via Apache suggests that the Zend files might not be accessible via the Apache process (that is, the user under which the Apache process runs).

`$ chmod 0777 /Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox/Library/PHP/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library`

to test.

You could probably get away with much less expansive permissions  - `0644`, for example - but I confess I'm terrible at that aspect of it. ;-)